# MD5 of the apk for that app?

Tags: android, md5, apk

How can I take the Md5 key for the apk installed in my device? Any suggestion whether its possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe something more? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to take the MD5 key for the apk installed in the device. I want to send that MD5 key to server for checking the number of install of the application

Comment: Just generate a `GUID` on first startup? Will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just want to get the MD5 checksum of an APK file?
If so, then:

> **Windows:** Download something like [WinMd5free](http://winmd5.com/) or [md5sums](http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/md5sums/)
>
> **Linux:** The **md5sum** command via command line / shell
>
> **OSX:** The **md5** command in Terminal

This may or may not make sense, depending on whether or not you're trying to do taxes or make toast. Because these programs do that.